# Showing that $(\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{ 0 \})$ $(\exists y \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{ 0 \})$ s.t. $xy \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod } p)$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

So far, my only progress is this:

> $xy \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod } p)$
>
> $\Rightarrow p \ | \ (xy-1)$
>
> $\Rightarrow xy-1=np$
>
> $\Rightarrow \displaystyle{y=\frac{np+1}{x}}$
>
> Since $p$ is prime, $np+1$ is guaranteed to be divisible.

How do I ensure $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \ | \ np+1$ and $y=\frac{np+1}{x} \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash \{ 0 \}$?

My only ideas were to perhaps say "since $np+1$ is composite, it has a prime divisor $\leq \sqrt{np+1}$," but I'm not how this helps my case at all, seemed like the only progress I could make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $p$ is prime, $\text{gcd}(x,p)=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p\backslash \{0\}$. By Bezout's lemma there exist $r,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $1 = rx+tp$, then $1 \equiv rx+tp\ \text{mod}\ p$, but $tp \equiv 0 \ \text{mod}\ p$, then $1 \equiv rx\ \text{mod}\ p$ (it is obvious $r \neq 0$). Finally, take $y = r$.

Answer (score 2):

First, take $x \neq 1$ since obviously $1*1=1 \bmod p.$ Thus, $x$ does not divide $p$ (as $p$ is prime and $x \neq 1$). Therefore, there exist nonzero integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ax+bp=1,$ thus $$ax+bp = (ax) \bmod p = (a \bmod p)(x \bmod p) \bmod p = 1 \bmod p.$$ Furthermore, $a$ cannot itself be a multiple of $p,$ or else $(ax+bp)=0 \bmod p,$ contradicting that $ax+bp=1.$ Thus $y:=a \bmod p$ exists and is in $\mathbb{Z}_p - 0$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map $f_x:\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Z}_p$ given by multiplication by $x$. That is,$$f_x(y)=xy,$$where multiplication is modulo $p$. Since $p$ is a prime, $f_x$ is one to one, hence onto.

Comment: I don't think I'm properly getting how you defined $f_x$. Could you explain what you meant by "multiplication by $x$"?

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek It may be more clear now.